# Passing props to the child in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two components. the App component which is the parent component and the Btn component which is the child component. How can i change the value of property text from the Btn component?

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.text = 'testing';
    this.onClicked = this.onClicked.bind(this);
  }

  onClicked() {
    this.text = 'changed';
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style = { styles.container }>
            <Text style = { styles.welcome }> { this.text } </Text>
            <Btn />
        </View>
    );
  }
}

class Btn extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        title = 'Button'
        onPress = { ? }
      />
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the parent component's onClicked function as a `prop` to the child component.

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

  ...

  render() {
    return (
        <View style = { styles.container }>
            <Text style = { styles.welcome }> { this.text } </Text>
            <Btn onClicked={this.onClicked}/>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

class Btn extends Component {

  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        title = 'Button'
        onPress = {this.props.onClicked}
      />
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are holding your `text` value in the wrong place. Hold it in your state. `constructor` runs once in the initial render and it does not run again like that. But, as a React way, if you hold your data in your state, whenever state changes your component rerenders and you see the updated data.

Then, you can pass your `onClick` handler to the child component and use it there. Here is the working snippet. I used `class-fields` so no need to write a constructor and an arrow function (no need to bind it).

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: "",
  }
  
  onClick = () =>
    this.setState({text: "foo bar" });

  
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Text is now: { this.state.text } </p>
            <Btn onClick={this.onClick} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

const Btn = ( props ) => (
      <button onClick={props.onClick}>Click</button>
)


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```